# the best practice for assigning an ID automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that contains a link like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="add()">new user </a>
```

When the user clicks the link, I add a new input field to the page.  I would like to assign an ID to that input field.  I can do this using Javascript:

```
var num=0;
function add(){
   num++;
   var input = document.createElement('input');
   input.setAttribute('ID',"input"+num);
}
```

This works; but my question is, is this the standard way, or is there a better way to do this, something that doesn't use num, JS or jQuery?

Comment: Maybe if only you quote `ID` in `setAttribute` method.

Comment: If i recall correctly, IDs cannot be integers?

Comment: @jcinacio they can on HTML5. Also OP is setting them to `"input"+num` :P

Comment: @jcinacio it is string and i compined "input" to num , so the ID becomes string

Comment: @Fabrício Matté thanks for the HTML5 info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *need* an ID on an input element. However you might be needing a `name`. If so, just use `name = "input[]"` - then on the server side you will get an array of values.

Comment: oh , u mean if i write this in JS , input.name = "input[]" , then on the server i can do that $values = $_POST['input'] ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var num=0;
function add(){
   num++;
   var input = document.createElement('input');
   input.id = "input"+num;
}
```

random ID without `num` :

```
function add(){
   var input = document.createElement('input');
   input.id = 'input'+parseInt(Math.random()*1354243242);
}
```

Comment: @adeneo but now how can he takes the value of that input fields with random IDS ?

Comment: The lower example just generates random ID's, and by random you of course have no way of knowing what the ID will be, so when accessing them later you will have to use `this` or possibly `index()`, `eq()` or a number of other ways that you can find an element etc. There is also the small chance that it will generate the same ID twice, it's really just an example, but usually it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery:

```
$('<input id="input'+ num +'"/>').appendTo('#yourElement')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the id to the element:

```
var num=0;
function add(){
   num++;
   var input = document.createElement('input');
   input.id = "input" + num;
}
```

**Since you tagged your question with jQuery, you can also do this:**

```
function add(){
    var input = $('<input id="input' + num++ +'" />')
    // do something with the input.
}
```

**Or:**

```
function add(){
    var input = $('<input>', {id = "input" + num++});
    // do something with the input.
}
```

**Update:**

**You can't create DOM elements without javascript** (jQuery is javascript).

Comment: yes this works good , i update my question to doesn't use mum ,thank you

Comment: @LinCR. **You can't create DOM elements without javascript** (jQuery is javascript).

Comment: ok i got you  , i will accept your answer after 6 mins , thank you

Comment: @LinCR. You should know one more **critical** thing, you can't have more than one element in the DOM with the same id at the same time. It's an invalid HTML.

Comment: but can i have more than js file , each one have the var with the same name ?

Comment: @LinCR. Not in the same scope. If you're not a javascript veteran, and you don't know how scopes work in javascript 1. Google `javascript scope` and learn about it 2. Just don't call two variables with the same name. I would suggest you to learn...

Comment: yes i will read about it , thank you for helping and for learning